# Swift - Passing DynamoDB Paginated Output results to function in another class

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am trying to pass the results of a DynamoDB function set-up in my Amazon.swift 'AWS' class back to my ViewController. The aim is to use the data to create GPS points on a map (the ViewController has the full MapKit / mapView setup).

This is the DynamoDB function:

```
func read_multipin_data() -> AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput { 

    let cond = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
    let v1   = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue(); v1.S = ADate
    cond.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperator.EQ
    cond.attributeValueList = [ v1 ]

    let exp = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    exp.scanFilter = [ "date" : cond ]

    self.scan(exp).continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
        let results = task.result as AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput
        return results // Error: 'AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput' is not convertible to 'BFTask'
    })
}

    func scan(expression : AWSDynamoDBScanExpression) -> BFTask! {

        let mapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
        return mapper.scan(AWS.self, expression: expression)
    }
```

The second function which currently merely attempts to recover the data in my ViewController is:

```
    @IBAction func refresh_db_pins(){

    let all_annotations_in: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput = AWS().read_multipin_data()   

    }
```

The error I am getting when I try to return the results is:
'AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput' is not convertible to 'BFTask'

I have tried many different approaches including converting the JSON formatted data into arrays, dictionaries, alas nothing worked.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your `read_multipin_data` method to something like:

```
func read_multipin_data() -> BFTask {

    let cond = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
    let v1   = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    v1.S = ADate
    cond.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperator.EQ
    cond.attributeValueList = [ v1 ]

    let exp = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    exp.scanFilter = [ "date" : cond ]

    return self.scan(exp);
}
```

Inside of `continueWithSuccessBlock`, you need to return either an instance of `BFTask` or `nil`, but you are returning an instance of `AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput`. That is why the compiler is complaining.